# how to assign a array of size 12000000000 in 'java' or greater than it and the array will be used for storing values

Tags: java

I got a problem that i have to find out number of  prime number which is sum of consecutive prime number.

input: N-> upto which i have to find out such numbers.
output: total number of prime number that meets condition described above.
for example:

```
input: N=17
output: 2
explanation: 5=2+3
             17=2+3+5+7
```

---

What i did is: first i store prime numbers in an array then i used another array which is summing the consecutive array and checking whether it is a prime number or no by using the 1st array in which prime numbers are stored, but to handle such a big number like 12000000000, it gives me an error.

I used long but no result. run time error continuously occurring.

Take a look in following line,
i assigned `long[] arr=new long[12000000000];`
it says error found! what to do how to do? please help me. 
my main question is " how can i handle such a big array?"

Please help me guys! Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Size of array can not be more than `int`. Use different approach.

Comment: Change the algorythm cause you are running out of memory :)

Comment: is there no way to handle such a big number?

Comment: So you want a `long` array with a ram size of ~89GB?? Good luck.

Comment: By the way thanks for your suggestion! :)

Comment: i'm a beginner Mr. luk. Guide me ...please

Comment: ok then suggest me another way or algorithm to solve this problem...please...

Comment: you do not need an array of that size, in your example for N=17 you only need an array of size 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a hashmap and a [big intege](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)r.

```
HashMap<BigInteger, Prime> primelist = new HashMap<BigInteger, Prime>();
```

You can see a live example on: 
https://ideone.com/Gjy4eM

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        HashMap<BigInteger, Prime> primelist = new HashMap<BigInteger, Prime>();
        BigInteger bigint = new BigInteger("12000000000");
        BigInteger one = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        for(int c=0;c<100;c++) {
            primelist.put(bigint, new Prime());
            bigint = bigint.add(one);
        }
        System.out.println(primelist);
    }
}
class Prime {
    // your stuff here
    public Prime() {
        // your prime initialisation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You cant!**

Some algorithms just cannot be implemented on real computers.

I would suggest you research other methods of generating prime numbers.

Perhaps a `HashSet` containing only the prime numbers you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList of Long values (no need for BigInteger) to hold the sums of consecutive primes as you find them, so you only use the memory that you need.  You shouldn't expect to find so many prime sums in your solution that you'd need to store 12,000,000,000 different sums.

You said you already have your array of primes, so start looking for series that start with 2 (your first prime), and work your way to the end.  Then start over looking for any that start with 3 (second prime), working to the end, and keeping moving your starting point through your array of primes.  That way, you're always reusing the prior sum calculated from a smaller series, but don't need to hold any intermediate data other than your sum itself.

Look for ways to optimize.  Like, if you stored a copy of your known primes into a hash table, then verifying each prime sum candidate is an O(1) operation, whereas searching through your array of primes might be O(log N) for each call.